# XML read using php

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

How to read the below xml using php?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<video>

<youtube> youtube video url </youtube>

</video>
```

I tried the code below but seems not working:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->load('new_result.xml');

$results = $dom->documentElement;

foreach( $results  as $result)

{

foreach( $result->getElementsByTagName('youtube') as $youtube )

{

echo ' video url ' . $youtube->nodeValue;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for anything fancy, just use `->getElementsByTagName()` method after you've loaded it up:

```
$dom->load('new_result.xml'); // load the file
// use ->getElementsByTagName() right away
$youtube = $dom->getElementsByTagName('youtube');
if($youtube->length > 0) { // if there are youtube nodes indeed
    foreach($youtube as $y) { // for each youtube node
        echo $y->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
if (file_exists('result.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('result.xml');

     echo $xml->youtube;
} else {
    exit('Failed to open result.xml.');
}
```

Comment: Assuming that there's only one `youtube` element in the whole XML, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMDocument::documentElement` is the root element node. In your XML, this would be the `video` element node. It is not a node list, but the actual node, so `foreach` will not work.

Just remove the outer `foreach`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('new_result.xml');
$video = $dom->documentElement;

foreach($video->getElementsByTagName('youtube') as $youtube) {
  echo ' video url ' . $youtube->nodeValue;
}
```

If you XML gets more complex you can use Xpath expressions:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('new_result.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('/video/youtube') as $youtube) {
  echo ' video url ' . $youtube->nodeValue;
}
```

Most Xpath expression will return node lists, but they can return scalar values. With that you can eliminate the second loop, too:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('new_result.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo ' video url ' . $xpath->evaluate('string(/video/youtube[1])');
```